# Why is dataclass field shared across instances

Tags: python, python-dataclasses

First time using dataclass, also not really good at Python. The following behaviour conflicts with my understanding so far:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class X:
  x: int = 1
  y: int = 2

@dataclass
class Y:
  c1: X = X(3, 4)
  c2: X = X(5, 6)

n1 = Y()
n2 = Y()

print(id(n1.c1))
print(id(n2.c1))

n1.c1.x = 99999
print(n2)
```

This prints

```
140459664164272
140459664164272
Y(c1=X(x=99999, y=4), c2=X(x=5, y=6))
```

Why does c1 behave like a class variable? What can I do to keep `n2.c1 != n1.c1`, do I need to write an init function?

I can get sensible results with this addition to Y:

```
  def __init__(self):
   self.c1 = X(3, 4)
   self.c2 = X(5, 6)
```

prints:

```
140173334359840
140173335445072
Y(c1=X(x=3, y=4), c2=X(x=5, y=6))
```

Comment: I believe [this](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html#mutable-default-values) answers exactly your question and shows how you can obtain what you want (using `field`).

Comment: Thanks, this is complicated but it works with field annotation. Feel free to add this as an answer.

Comment: Like I said, the link was already the answer. Cheers! :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Why does `c1` behave like a class variable?

Because you specified *default value* for them and they're now a class attribute. In the [Mutable Default Values](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html#mutable-default-values) section, it's mentioned:

> Python stores default member variable values in class attributes.

But look at this:

```py
@dataclass
class X:
    x: int = 1
    y: int = 2

@dataclass
class Y:
    c1: X
    c2: X = X(5, 6)

print("c1" in Y.__dict__)  # False
print("c2" in Y.__dict__)  # True
```

`c1` doesn't have default value so it's not in class's namespace.

Indeed by doing so(defining default value), Python stores that `c1` and `c2` inside both instance's namespace (`n1.__dict__`) and class's namespace (`Y.__dict__`). Those are the same objects, only the reference is passed:

```py
@dataclass
class X:
    x: int = 1
    y: int = 2

@dataclass
class Y:
    c1: X = X(3, 4)
    c2: X = X(5, 6)

n1 = Y()
n2 = Y()

print("c1" in Y.__dict__)  # True
print("c1" in n1.__dict__)  # True

print(id(n1.c1)) # 140037361903232
print(id(n2.c1)) # 140037361903232
print(id(Y.c1))  # 140037361903232
```

So now, If you want them to be different you have several options:

1. Pass arguments while instantiating (Not a good one):

```py
@dataclass
class X:
    x: int = 1
    y: int = 2

@dataclass
class Y:
    c1: X = X(3, 4)
    c2: X = X(5, 6)

n1 = Y(X(3, 4), X(5, 6))
n2 = Y(X(3, 4), X(5, 6))

print("c1" in Y.__dict__)  # True
print("c1" in n1.__dict__)  # True

print(id(n1.c1)) # 140058585069264
print(id(n2.c1)) # 140058584543104
print(id(Y.c1))  # 140058585065088
```

2. Use `field` and pass [`default_factory`](https://peps.python.org/pep-0557/#default-factory-functions):

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass, field

@dataclass
class X:
    x: int = 1
    y: int = 2

@dataclass
class Y:
    c1: X = field(default_factory=lambda: X(3, 4))
    c2: X = field(default_factory=lambda: X(5, 6))

n1 = Y()
n2 = Y()

print("c1" in Y.__dict__)   # False
print("c1" in n1.__dict__)  # True

print(id(n1.c1))  # 140284815353136
print(id(n2.c1))  # 140284815353712
```

In the second option, because I didn't specify `default` parameter(you can't mix both), nothing is going to be stored in the class's namespace. `field(default=SOMETHING)` is another way of saying `= SOMETHING`.

Comment: Thanks, I'll use field with default factory = X, no lambda. I'm really curious whether storing default member values in class attributes is really favorable in most cases. This reminds me of the default function args as in `def f(x={}):...` which is also quite confusing.

Comment: @perreal In fact `default_factory` is the correct way of handling mutable objects. You usually don't want to share mutable objects between instances. same problem with mutable parameters! look at [this example](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html#dataclasses.field) and the definition of the `default_factory`.

Comment: Fairly confusing topic without particularly explanations; but your example link is helpful @S.B and does shed some light on why is default_factory needed here